# Javascript onclick requiring two clicks

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this box that transforms in a bigger box when clicked (getting class).
But it is taking 2 clicks, and not only one as it was suposed to take.

```
.clientes {width:170px;height:27px;background-image:url('../imagens/clients.gif');-webkit-transition:1s;}
.clientes-clicked {width:356px !important;height:154px !important;background-image:url('../imagens/clients-big.png') !important;-webkit-transition:1s;}

<script>    
    var clientesclick = function(){
    $('.clientes').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.clientes').toggleClass("clientes-clicked"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using $(document).ready()? Also, why are you storing the function in a variable instead of just using assingning the event handler? Those two might mbe the reasons, if not, we might need some more information, like other scripts you're runing in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. You could simply do:

```
$('.clientes').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clientes-clicked');
});
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64XQ3/

And, as was pointed out above, your jQuery should be wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

Comment: You're right, it's not working on your site, but it's not because of the code itself. The syntax is correct. This probably has something to do with other scripts interfering with each other. I'd try getting rid of the scripts one-by-one and re-trying your `toggleClass()` method each time.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.clientes').on('click', function(e) {
          $('.clientes').toggleClass("clientes-clicked"); //you can list several class names 
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Not too sure why you are assigning it to a variable but it would not run right away, instead it will be executed when you call that method (I guess this is first click) and then afterwards your dom elements will have the event (second click).

Using $(document).ready it will run once all the dom is ready, then when you first click on your elements they should already have the event

Comment: I tried on document.ready but its not working look: finecolor.com.br/novo

Comment: It is actually because your .clientes is not there on document ready, it is only appearing when you click on the menu. You should execute the code after the menu click event (after the popover appears). Does that make sense ?

Comment: It certainely does because it works now. Thank you sir!