# Javascript onclick() requires two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

I have three buttons, each calls `chooseMap()` function `onclick` which then redirects user to a new page based on button `id`. Everything works but I have to click twice every time. Can anyone tell me why this is, and how I can fix it?

```
<div class="row text-center" onclick="chooseMap();">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="world" >World Map</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="europe">Europe</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sweden">Sweden</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function chooseMap(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("sweden").onclick = function(){
      location.href = "map_game/sweden.html";
    }
    document.getElementById("europe").onclick = function(){
      location.href="map_game/europe.html";
    }
    document.getElementById("world").onclick = function(){
      location.href="map_game/world.html";
    }
  })
}
```

Everything works. I click on the button, function is called, passes the correct string and I'm merrily sent to the next page where everything also works. BUT, I have to click twice on the button to make it work. First time I click nothing happens. Any thoughts?

I already researched this question on Stack Overflow but was not able to address my issue via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852932/javascript-onclick-requires-two-clicks) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299145/javascript-onclick-requiring-two-clicks) question.

Comment: Can you place your code in fiddle ?

Comment: why you put `document.ready` within `chooseMap` function

Comment: Most likely chooseMap is not called, when the document is loaded but when you click your button the first time. Then the click event is registered with the button and fires the second time you click it. Is that possible?

Comment: its hard to wrap some buttons in a href link you need to use jquery

Comment: Super super classic question. You attach your clicks inside another function, so the clicks become active only after that function is called.

Comment: I realize just how newbie my question was since everyone was able to solve it in two seconds :)

Newbie thanks everybody, I can't even upvote questions yet, don't have enough rep

Comment: seems my answer is not good :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is because the first click executes the `chooseMap` function which then attaches the event handler. The second click then executes the code that's assigned in those event handlers.

To fix and improve your code, remove the inline `onclick` attribute and use jQuery to attach your events. Try this:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="world">World Map</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="europe">Europe</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sweden">Sweden</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sweden").click(function() {
        window.location.assign('map_game/sweden.html');
    });
    $("#europe").click(function() {
        window.location.assign('map_game/europe.html');
    });
    $("#world").click(function() {
        window.location.assign('map_game/world.html');
    });
});
```

Note that you could even improve this further by using DRY principles you can use a single handler based on the `class` of the `button` elements, and set the URL using the `id` of the button, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        window.location.assign('map_game/' + this.id + '.html');
    })
});
```

Comment: The DRY example is great but Y jQuery, the same thing can be achieved with addEventListener, is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Nope you could use `addEventListener` too. I provided a jQuery example as the OP seems to be in a halfway house situation. If you have jQuery included in the page, you may as well use it :)

Comment: I've tried this, but sometimes my button takes two clicks. I can reproduce this with consistency by pressing enter in a text area, then clicking the button.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie that sounds like you've got nested event handlers. I'd suggest starting a new question about it if it's an issue

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery for event handling, you are using it anyway:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sweden').on('click', function () {
        location.href = "map_game/sweden.html";
    });
    $('#europe').on('click', function () {
        location.href = "map_game/europe.html";
    });
    $('#world').on('click', function () {
        location.href = "map_game/world.html";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row text-center" onclick="chooseMap();">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="map_game/sweden.html"
    ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="world" >World Map</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="map_game/europe.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="europe">Europe</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="map_game/world.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sweden">Sweden</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```